# No object option when adding a geometry bevel to a curve?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, geometry, bevel

I'm trying to extrude a circle along a bezier curve. Normall i would create a specific object ( in this case a circle with 32 verts) and use that as the bevel object for my bezier curve to refer to.

However in 2.8, I go to select a 'bevel object' and just get a blank panel, no options at all ( there are several mesh objects in my scene). Any ideas why this might be?

Also, I can't select anything in the 'taper object' panel either - Nothing in the box at all.

Please help!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sussed, it, Idiot me was using a mesh circle rather than a curve circle

Comment: We've all been there :). Glad you solved it yourself.

Comment: That makes us idiots? That was not obvious from the sources I was searching.

Comment: same issue here lol